# Android ListView Slow when displaying Profile Avatar with tweet

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Currently, I'm pulling 15 tweets into an ArrayList using a Handler and then passing the completed ArrayList to a updateUI method.  It's working great so far, but when my ListView is populated, the scrolling experience is very choppy.  When I remove the images reference from my TwitterAdapter the ListView has a fast/smooth user experience.  I suspect my Adapter is attempting to re-dowload each graphic when I'm scrolling, but can't get the debugger to hitch on that method to prove it.

Here is the key code within the Activity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_BambooZen);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.twitter_layout);

        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.TwitterListView);         

        /*
         * Remove any existing callbacks to the handler before adding the new handler, 
         * to make absolutely sure we don't get more callback events than we want.
         */
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateAdapterTask);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateAdapterTask, 1000);  //Fire the Handler once, the handler will manage self-calls        

    }   

    private Runnable mUpdateAdapterTask = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {

               try{ 

                 //Get Twitter Tweets on separate thread (Requires Network)                 
                 ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = getTweets("Formula1", 1);                
                 updateUI(tweets);

                 //Refresh every 45 seconds = 45000
                 mHandler.postDelayed(this, 45000); 

               }
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                   e.toString();
               }
           }
    };

    /*
     *  Rebuilds the Tweets on UIThread
     */
    public void updateUI(ArrayList<Tweet> tweets){
        adapter = new TwitterAdapter(this, R.layout.twitter_listitem, tweets);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

The Item Adapter:

```
public class TwitterItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> {

    public TwitterItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmap(String bitmapUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(bitmapUrl);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection() .getInputStream()); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {return null;}
    }
}
```

The Twitter Adapter:

```
public class TwitterAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet>{

    private ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;

    public TwitterAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Tweet> tweets) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, tweets);
        this.tweets = tweets;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.twitter_listitem, null);
        }

        Tweet tweet = tweets.get(position);
        if (tweet != null) {
            TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.username);
            TextView message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);

            if (username != null) {
                username.setText(tweet.username);
            }

            if(message != null) {
                message.setText(tweet.message);
            }

            if(image != null) {
                image.setImageBitmap(TwitterItemAdapter.getBitmap(tweet.image_url));                
            }
        }
        return v;
    }   
}
```

Comment: yes it downloads them all the time since you do image.setImageBitmap(TwitterItemAdapter.getBitmap()) in getView

Comment: Thanks, you were correct.. ListView was attempting to download all the time.

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect my Adapter is attempting to re-dowload each graphic when I'm scrolling

Yes.

`getView()` of `TwitterAdapter` is called on the main application thread. In there, you are calling `getBitmap()` (on a completely pointless `TwitterItemAdapter` class), which is downloading the image from the Internet.

There are probably two dozen implementations of a background image loader available, with varying degrees of sophistication, from [an SDK sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/src/com/example/android/xmladapters/ImageDownloader.html) to [blog posts](http://blog.georgenguyen.info/index.php/2012/use-asynctask-to-apply-lazy-loading-images-for-your-android-application/) to [whole app frameworks](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/).

Comment: Solid source, I ended up going with the SDK example, it worked like a charm by putting the following code in my Adapter and deleted the pointless List Adapter, I was going somewhere else with that.

AvatarDownloader av = new AvatarDownloader();    
av.download(tweet.image_url, image);